# How to do html cache in remote server save and load?

Tags: php

When I put following codes in my header and footer. The html cache is saved to local server.
I want to save it remote server then cache file will load from remote server.

header codes

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];
$cachefile = 'cached-'.substr_replace($file ,"",-4).'.html';
$cachetime = 18000;

// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
    readfile($cachefile);
    exit;
}
ob_start(); // Start the output buffer
?>
```

Footer codes

```
<?php
// Cache the contents to a cache file
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
?>
```

Any solution?